# Generate colorful QR code

Tags: iphone, sdk, qr-code

I want to generate the colorful QR code.
I had used [https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/)  code to generate the QR code.
now the qr code generated is always n black color.I want to make it in Red or any
other color. 
The coding of coloring And the drawing of QR code .png image is done QR_Draw_png.mm file.
What should i edit in [QR_Draw_png.mm](https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator/blob/master/QRGen/qr_draw_png.mm) this file.
How to do the generate the colorful qr code.

How is it possible.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi Shweta, This is Dinesh from chennai. I am using the same kuapay in my application. But it works only for the first time. If i try to regenerate again without closing the app. then the app crashes automatically. Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best example to generate colorful QR code.

http://www.oscarsanderson.com/2013/08/12/implementing-a-qr-code-generator-on-the-iphone/

You will found qrencode library from above link, and Category of UIImage.

After you need to simple call this method with your selected Color to generate it.

```
mgView.image = [UIImage QRCodeGenerator:txtCouponName.text
                          andLightColour:[UIColor whiteColor]
                           andDarkColour:[UIColor blackColor]
                            andQuietZone:1
                                 andSize:300];
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to tinker with the Z-Bar code to do that.

Maybe these links might help:

http://mashable.com/2011/04/18/qr-code-design-tips/

http://qreateandtrack.com/2011/01/06/adding-a-bit-of-color-to-your-qr-codes/

and

http://keremerkan.net/qr-code-and-2d-code-generator/

Comment: @Kinghthong Thanks for the reply.I had edited my code..Can u please help me on it..Please it is

Answer (score 0):

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063575/generate-colorful-qr-code%2F&choe=UTF-8

Use this link same generate web,android,iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

```
     QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    try {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
// set colors for QR code
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_result_qr)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```